# Git: Restore uncomitted changes from new branch

Tags: git

If I have a local git repo with unstaged changes in **branch1**, then do the following:

1. Checkout to a new branch: **branch2**
2. Commit some (not all) files
3. Run `git reset --hard`from **branch2**
4. Checkout back to **branch1**

How can I do this without losing changes in **branch1**? Do I have to run `git stash` from within **branch1** or **branch2** or commit those files first? Or can I still recover my uncommitted changes from before using git?

Comment: Step 3 got rid of all uncommitted, unstashed, and unstaged changes.

Comment: You do __not__ have unstaged changes in branch1. Unstaged (and uncommited) changes are not in the repository, hence not in any branch.

Comment: Don't use `--hard` in step 3, I think that would do it in most cases.

Comment: "How can I do this without losing changes in branch1?" What is "this" supposed to be? Clearly you don't like what you did do, and I can see why. But what did you _intend_ to do? For example, suppose you are on branch1 and you edit but do not commit files a, b, and c. You switch to branch2 and commit files a and b, and then switch back to branch1. Now tell me what branch2 should look like, and what the working tree should look like, with respect to files a, b, and c.

Answer (score 1):

You can either leave out `--hard` when running `git reset` because that is what reverts your unstaged changes. If that is not feasable for some reason you have to use `git stash`.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental error you're making here is thinking that "changes" (staged or unstaged) are "in a branch".  They're not!  This is true no matter which meaning we use, of the many meanings of the word *branch* that Git has.  In fact, in a very important sense, as [tkausl commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72835610/git-restore-uncomitted-changes-from-new-branch#comment128648526_72835610), the work you're doing, as you're doing work, isn't really *in the repository* at all.

Too many Git introductory tutorials begin by implying, or maybe even outright claiming, that Git is about files and branches.  It isn't: it's really all about *commits*.  The *commits* are what go in the repository, or most of what goes in.  Once something is committed, it's safely preserved forever—well, *almost* forever and *almost* safe (you can always completely destroy the repository entirely for instance).  So we should focus first on the commits.

Unfortunately, commits themselves seem all abstract and vague.  If you ask Git to show you a commit—using, e.g., `git show`—you get this sort of output:

```
$ git show
commit e4a4b31577c7419497ac30cebe30d755b97752c5 (tag: v2.37.0, ...)
Author: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
Date:   Mon Jun 27 09:17:55 2022 -0700

    Git 2.37
    
    Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>

diff --git a/GIT-VERSION-GEN b/GIT-VERSION-GEN
index 120af376c1..b210b306b7 100755
--- a/GIT-VERSION-GEN
+++ b/GIT-VERSION-GEN
@@ -1,7 +1,7 @@
 #!/bin/sh
 
 GVF=GIT-VERSION-FILE
-DEF_VER=v2.37.0-rc2
+DEF_VER=v2.37.0
 
 LF='
 '
```

Is that a commit?  Well, it's a *representation of* a commit, just as the image below is a *representation* of a woman.  It's not actually the woman, it's a painting.  But it's not actually a painting either: it's a JPG *of* a painting.  Note how we may have to go around and around before we can even agree on what something really *is*.  That's one of the problems we have, defining what a *commit* is.

[image: Mona Lisa]

Still, once we've used Git for a bit, we have at least a pretty good vague idea of what a commit is: it's a numbered (by hash ID) entity, like commit `e4a4b31577c7419497ac30cebe30d755b97752c5` above.  **We *can* use Git for a long time without knowing much more than this, but we *shouldn't*.**

#### The absolute minimum you need to know when using Git

There is, unfortunately, a *lot* that we need to know, at least eventually.  *Git is tricky!*  There's a lot to learn about it.  But there's a bare minimum to know so that you won't get into trouble, and it goes like this:

- A *repository* stores *commits*.  That's not necessarily all it stores, but that's the main thing.
- A *commit* is a numbered (by hash ID) thingy that stores *files and metadata*.
- Each commit stores a *full snapshot of every file*, plus that metadata.  The snapshot is just that—a snapshot—and the metadata remembers "stuff about this commit itself", such as the name and email address of the person who made it.
- All parts of every commit are frozen for all time.  Nothing *in* a commit can ever be changed!  If a commit is terrible, we can *stop using it*, by making a new and improved version that we use instead.  But that won't make the old commit stop *existing*.  Then again, as in the old riddle, if a tree falls in the forest and there's no one around to hear it, does it make a "noise" (where "noise" means "offends all the people who heard it")?  If you can't *find* a commit, does it matter if it exists?
- *Git* finds commits by those big ugly hash IDs.  *Humans* are bad at those, so Git gives us things like *branch names* too.  The names we use—branch names, tag names, and all other kinds of names—store the hash IDs for us.  Each name actually stores just *one* hash ID, but that's good enough.
- Because commit snapshots are all frozen (the files in the commits are magically de-duplicated too—that becomes important soon, but you don't *have* to know it right away), you literally *can't* work on the *committed* files.  So you don't.  The act of *checking out* a commit, with `git checkout` or `git switch`, tells Git to *extract the saved files*.  These become *ordinary files* that you can use and work on / with.
- These ordinary files are *not in the repository!*  (Well, to some extent this depends on exactly how we define *repository*, but to keep this list short, let's not get into this.)  They are, instead, in your *working tree* or *work-tree*.
- Last, Git makes *new* commits from a thing it calls by several names: the *index*, or the *staging area*, or—rarely these days—the *cache*.  The existence of this thing is why Git makes you run `git add` so much, and it explains a whole lot of other Git weirdness.

When you're just getting started, you can remain kind of fuzzy on this index / staging-area thing.  Just remember that it exists and it's important—it holds your *proposed next commit*—and get around to learning more about it soon.

Once you *really know* these eight minimum things, you can get some work done in Git.  You can refer back to its [manual pages](https://git-scm.com/docs) and some of them *might* even start to make a little bit of sense.

[The `git reset` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) is, unfortunately, a very large and complicated command that does a lot of things.  But you'll see that—as [SebDieBin answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72837567/1256452)—`--hard` erases *working tree* files, replacing them with files that come out of some commit.  Since you've memorized the above points by now—well, maybe you have—you will know that the working tree files aren't actually *in* the repository.  They may have come out of some commit, but if you've *changed* them since then, the updated files are *only there in the working tree*.  Erasing those files—removing them and replacing them with committed versions instead—therefore erases your changes, and since those changes were never *in* Git, Git can't help you get them back.

You *can* take this to mean *`git reset --hard` is scary, be careful with it*, which is good advice.  But this doesn't really go far enough: there are a lot of *other* Git operations that can remove, forever, Git's ability to help you get back *unsaved* changes.  What you really need to know is what makes you *safer*.  Once you've *committed* something—made a full snapshot of every file from Git's *index* or *staging-area*—the *committed* files are safely stored for as long as you can find that commit's hash ID.  Well, and, as long as your laptop doesn't catch fire, for instance.

[image: Laptopt on fire]

Comment: Actually it's some pixels on my computer monitor that are illuminated in such a way as to represent the instructions contained in the JPEG.